# Is it permissible for a girl to chat with men online or follow them on Twitter?

Tags: nikah, relationships, zina

I am girl and I don't usually talk to men but since I have started college so I have spoken to a few guys.

Previously I had fell in love with a guy and was flirting with him over the internet. Currently, I follow many guys on Twitter and they follow me back too. Their's and my tweets are Islamic.

I really want to get married but if I don't talk to guys then I don't think I will be able to find a good Muslim guy to marry. And that's why I use these online medium of communication.

Given the above, is it permissible to chat with men online and follow them on Twitter?

Comment: Sister, this is probably not a proper answer to your question and I was going to comment it but I think you will find this link beneficial inshAllah. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eX_zzgQwj6w May Allah keep you high in health and imaan.

Comment: See [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26050/is-it-allowed-to-make-relations-with-non-mehrams-in-social-media/26056#26056)

Comment: at that time following also meant allowing to send private messages: https://web.archive.org/web/20140220073509/http://support.twitter.com:80/articles/14606 . another additional function of following is showing you exist. (and the primary meaning of it is subscription to [public] tweets).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chatting with guys online will do no good to you. It is just not permissible in Islam. If you think you need to attract a good Muslim man, than chatting with boys won't help, nor will following them on Twitter.

Get closer to Allah, purify yourself , so that He will purify one for you. Start wearing an Abayah. Many good Muslim men search for women who veil and cover themselves properly. Also consider this: if they are Good Muslims they would probably never chat with a woman online.

Believe me, every woman has a tendency to attract other men. **Every woman** feels good when she is praised. *But* you have to control that.

The *main* purpose of hijab after all is so that women don't attract men.

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer. I would also like to add that (being a man) I can say that women who talk and flirt easily with men are not really considered good "wife material." On the other hand, a good hijabi woman, though not glamorous, are universally considered to be good potential wives (even among non-Muslim men). So to the OP sister and other sisters, please take the hint!

Comment: there are no prooflinks (to ayats and hadithes) in this answer

Answer (score -4):

No because its like dating and flirting which is haram. The prophet said men and women should be separate so Muslim women shouldn't be friends with guys or chat. If you wanted to get married tell your parents. They'll find someone suitable

Comment: "The prophet said men and women should be separate" - i would like to see a prooflink (http or book reference) for this. "so Muslim women shouldn't be friends with guys or chat" - do not you think you make too far conclusion?